Proof Kolmogorov Zero One Law for lim sup
Let $\{\xi_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be independent random variables with distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Denote $S_n = \xi_1 + \cdots + \xi_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha > 0$, the following is true:
$ \mathbb{P} \left( \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n^\alpha} \le x \right) \in \{0, 1\} $
Hint. First, show that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the considered event is independent of the random vector $(\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_k)$.
I tried to do what was indicated in the hint, but I don’t even understand what to do with it later. I found various proofs of Kolmagorov’s theorem, but none of them were clear to me; everywhere there was complex work with sigma algebras, which was not clear to me. (We haven't studied the Kolmogorov Zero One Law so I can't use it)

The event is independent of $(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_k)$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$. Therefore it is independent of $\sigma(\xi_n,\,n\in\mathbb N)$. But is is obviously $\sigma(\xi_n,\,n\in\mathbb N)$-measurable. So it is independent of itself hence trivial.
